# Crystal Reports 2008 Display different versions of report based on parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, subreports

I have a crystal report that is already distributed dynamically by a parameter (in this case, physician).

I have four different types of physicians (A, B, C, D) and I'd like to send a different version of the report to each type.

Within a single .rpt file can I group 4 different report types (subreports?) so that a physician of type A sees a different version than a physician of type B?

I need this to be a pdf so I can't do any drilldown.

I apologize for being a total noob & appreciate any pointers. Thank you.

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 Version 12.5.0.1190.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If there are few differences between the layouts, i probably would not use subreports (they may slow down the report). I would make different sessions and suppress them accordingly.

For example, suppose the datasource is one table with 10 columns. The first layout needs the columns 1 to 8. The second needs the columns 1, 5, 9, 10. So, i would make 2 different details sessions and suppress thema according to the parameters.

If the layouts are too diferent, i would make different RPT files and use the parameters to choose wich one i would pass to Crystal Reports.

If you may be more specific, maybe i can put more details.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I am trying to do.